# How to calculate percentile.exe in R like we do in MS excel

Tags: r, excel

How to calculate percentile.exc in r

I have some retail data where I need calculate the percentile (25th and 75th), mean median and the count based on Order_ID and Product ID. Checking upon the result with Excel calculation mean and median coming out correct but my percentile values are not matching.

25th Perc-13087.5, Average-24313.51667, Median-20167, 75th Perc-38916.25

```
     pivot_MRP <- Test %>% group_by(Product_Code) %>% 
                summarise(MRP_25 = quantile(MRP,0.25), 
                          MRP_Median = median(MRP),
                          MRP_1_Avg = mean(MRP), 
                          MRP_75 = quantile(MRP, 0.75),
                          MRP_count = n())
```

```
        pivot_Disc <- Test %>% group_by(Order_ID) %>% 
            summarise(MRP_25 = quantile(MRP,0.25), 
                      MRP_Median = median(MRP),
                      MRP_1_Avg = mean(MRP), 
                      MRP_75 = quantile(MRP, 0.75),
                      MRP_count = n())
```

Comment: What does `percentile.exe` do? Is it some program?

Comment: @NelsonGon I'm pretty sure he means the ``percentile.exc`` function, it is a function from Excel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate percentile in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329408/how-to-calculate-percentile-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

Use `quantile` function.

```
data<-c(1,1,2,2,3,3) #Your data
quantile(data,c(0,0.25,0.5,0.75)) # Data and a vector of probabilities
```

Then you have.

```
  0%   25%   50%  75% 
  1.00 1.25 2.00 2.75
```

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo.... but is does not serve my purpose.... I am looking for the percentile.exe method... what you have suggested in percentile.inc...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer.

I figure out my self and found the answer.

```
                summarise(MRP_25 = quantile(MRP,0.25, type=6), 
                          MRP_Median = median(MRP),
                          MRP_1_Avg = mean(MRP), 
                          MRP_75 = quantile(MRP, 0.75, type=6),
                          MRP_count = n())'''

all we need add is 'type=6' in quantile

Thanks you all :)
```